# Young measure generated by sequence

Tags: measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

It's about the following exercise:

$i)$ Let $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $h(x)=\begin{cases} a,\; 0 \leq x < \lambda \\ b, \; \lambda \leq x < 1.\end{cases}$. The function $h$ can be continued periodically on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $w_n(x)=h(nx)$. Determine the Young measure generated by $\{w_n\}$.

$ii)$ Let $h:[0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. Continue $h$ periodically on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $w_n(x)=h(nx)$. Determine the Young measure generated by $\{w_n\}$.

I was able to do the first exercise. The Young measure is $\nu(x)=\lambda\delta_{\{a\}}+(1-\lambda)\delta_{\{b\}}$. But I am not really sure that I understand $ii)$ correctly: I suppose the $h$ in $ii)$ is the same $h$ as in $i)$, only with arguments in $\mathbb{R}^n$? But if this is true, shouldn't the Young measure be the same as in $i)$? And if not, why not and why can't I prove this the same way I proved $i)$? I would appreciate a little help with exercise $ii)$ because it isn't completely clear to me where exactly the difference to exercise $i)$ is.

Comment: What is your definition for a sequence of $L^1$ functions to generate a Young measure?

Comment: We don't really have a definition for such sequences, we only have the following statement about the Young-measure generated by a sequence:

Comment: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n, K \subset \mathbb{R}$ bounded and open and let $w_n:\Omega \rightarrow K$ be a sequence of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ functions. Then we have a subsequence $w_{n_k}$ and a weak-$*$ measurable Young-measure $\nu:\Omega \rightarrow M(\overline{K})$ with $\nu(x)\geq 0$, $\int_{\overline{K}}d\nu(x)=1$ for a.e. $x\in \Omega$ and for every function $f \in C(\overline{K})$ we have $f(w_{n_k}) \rightharpoonup \overline{f}$ in terms of weak-$*$ convergence in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\overline{f}(x):=\int_{\overline{K}}fd\nu(x)$, for a.e. $x\in \Omega$.